# R Programming Issue: Passing characters to matrix converts them to a number

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to write a pretty simple for loop where I'm passing a name from the top row of one data frame to a space in another matrix. I'm having the issue where when I try to do this, the name that I am trying to pass to the matrix is instead showing up as a number in the matrix (which turns out to be the number in a cell down 4 rows from the name in the original data frame).

Here's some of my code with the results I get:

**mock_board** is an 8x14 matrix that I am trying to pass names to

**ADPsort** is a large data frame with all kinds of names and statistics that is sorted by a category so that the name I want to pull is at the top row of the data frame.

all I'm trying to do is: mock_board[1,1] <- ADPsort[1,1] (there's more too it in the actual program, but even when breaking it down so far it still gives me the error)

here is what I am getting (commands in regular, computer response in italics):

ADPsort[1,1]   -    *Player Name*

mock_board[1,1] - *NA*

but after

mock_board[1,1] <- ADPsort[1,1]

mock_board[1,1] - *4*

So for some reason instead of passing player name to mock_board[1,1], R is passing 4 instead. I tried changing the matrix to a data frame but all that did was make mock_board[1,1] = "4" after attempting to pass "Player Name" to it. I've been stuck on this for a while and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to fixing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a `factor` not a `character` to a numeric matrices. Hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: Good call - I just checked the class type for the name column and the class came up as "factor". Any advice on how to fix it knowing that?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it using data$name <- as.character(data$name). Thanks a ton for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the name column was of the factor class - used as.character to convert the column to character class and everything works fine now